# Морфемный состав слов "образование" и "образовать"

Tags: словообразование, морфология, морфемика

Сколько же версий морфемного состава слова "образование"! К примеру: *образ-ова-ни-е*, *образов-а-ниj-е* (о каком-то наросте и т. п. или о действии к гл. образовать), *образов-аниj-е* (о процессе обучения), *образова-ниj-е* (Викисловарь, ссылающийся на Тихонова). Я бы вообще разобрал так: *образ-ова-н-иj-е*.

Такая же путаница с глаголом: и *образ-ова-ть*, и *образов-а-ть*, и *образова-ть*...

Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Разбор слова по составу онлайн**: образова/ни/е.

**Всё остальное - только мое мнение** .

1) Корень ОБРАЗОВА - **смотрится удручающе**, но причина ясна: образование человека - это процесс усвоения им знаний, обучение, просвещение, а не  создание/образование самого человека. Эта несложная идея требует от учащихся при **морфемном разборе** изображения  таких "монстров", как корень ОБРАЗОВА -.

2) **Но давайте обратимся к этимологии:**

**образ** - X-XI  вв, от общеславянского "образити" - изобразить, нарисовать (разити,  а также резать, разить - у всех этих слов один и.-е. корень). Значение слова: "образ - это нечто, получившее новый лик или вид" (Черных).

**образовать** - XI -ХШ вв, от старославянского "образъ"

**образование** - XIX в, калька с немецкого Bildung

3) Из современного толкового словаря: **ОБРАЗОВАТЬ, ; образованный;  что. Устар.** Дать **образование**  О. и воспитать детей.

4) Итак, существовал глагол "образовать", связанный с обучением, эта связь: образовать (=создать) - образовать (обучить, воспитать) -  ясно прослеживается в языке: **обучая, мы создаем образ нового человека.**

5) Вследствие всего сказанного, **предлагается единая схем разбора для всех случаев:** образ/ова/ть - образ/ова/нн/ый, образ/ова/ни/е.

**Занимая наших школьников подобной формалистикой, мы "крадем" у них драгоценное время**, которое даже в рамках русского языка можно использовать с гораздо большей пользой: не умеем грамотно писать, не умеем грамотно говорить, зато имеем несколько схем разбора для одного слова.